# How to Redirect to particular view in Session_End method in Global.asax using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to redirect to particular view in Session_End method in Global.asax using asp.net

I tried using Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index") but it is giving error like "Response is unrecognized in Global.asax".

Comment: Maybe you want a sign out link and an info page:) to redirect after they click sign out

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Session_End could be fired without an actual HTTP context. The user might have even closed his browser long before this event gets fired so there is nowhere to redirect to. The Request and Response objects are not available.

Conclusion: don't do this.

Comment: I found the following blog post(http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/index.php/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/) that claims to to solve the problem but it doesn't work for me.                 The IsNewSession condition is true but the condition              if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)) { // handle expired session }                                                           always returns false and it never handles the invalid session. I'm confused.